ExtJS tooltip without masking background
I'm working on an extJS classic 6.5 application that has some functionality implemented as a subclass of Ext.tip.ToolTip, and it works fine except that when the tooltip is activated the background is covered by a grey (technically rgba(0,0,0,0.4)) <div> that we don't want.
We cannot merely hide this <div> because there are other tooltips that we do want the <div> to appear underneath.
What is the best way to turn off masking the background for a specific tooltip?

Turns out someone had marked the tooltip as modal and I'd missed it. Whoops.
